# Using "logging in" correctly

Tags: verbs, conjugation

There are a lot of questions concerning the correct use if *login*, *log in*, etc.

When speaking directly to an use I would say

> You can always change this permission by logging in in the internal download area [...]

because after the "logging in" I naturally would do a very short pause before continuing with an emphasis on "in the internal download area".

However when I wrote it down on the site I'm developing, I didn't like it. The double "in" seems wrong o to me but I don't know how to express that in better way. Could anyone help me here? What about "by logging into the internal"?

Comment: Here's an [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=logging+in%2Clogging+into%2Clogging+on%2C+logging+onto&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clogging%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogging%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogging%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clogging%20onto%3B%2Cc0) for your reference. Click the entries at the bottom of the page to see how each term is used.

Comment: You can certainly do it.  Better to avoid if it's not too awkward to do so, but it's not worth losing sleep over, unless you are writing something that will be read by thousands of people every day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The double *in* is not good.
There are other ways:

> by logging to the internal...
>
> by logging on the internal...
>
> by logging on to the internal...
>
> by logging in on the internal...
>
> by logging in on to the internal...

You are quite right in wanting to change the double *in*. English has a grand selection of prepositions, and I think a little thought will just about always produce a good alternative for situations like this.

Comment: I like the `logging on the internal...` one. I think I'll use that

Comment: What about: Logging in to the internal... ?

Comment: 'In in' strings are reasonably common and aren't always seen as poor style. ' "Division" played out on television screens across the world as people tuned in in record numbers to the BBC Parliament channel.' There would be a slight pause between the particle and the preposition when spoken; {tuned in} {in record numbers}.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth There is nothing "wrong" with in in. But I would prefer "watched in record numbers" .It is my prejudice, and I want to keep it.

Comment: "Logging on" is the wrong terminology if you're using credentials according to [this](https://writingexplained.org/log-in-or-log-on-difference) *and* [this](https://grammarist.com/usage/log-on-log-in/) source, while [cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/log-in-on) doesn't seem to care.... i am more confused as before!

Comment: Logging in at the . . .

Answer (score 0):

A double "in" will always be bad, even if it's not actually wrong.

Why not just avoid it, by using different wording?

"You can always change this permission. Log (in on/into) the internal download area."